# Python - how to use mainframe() method in QWebEnginePage [error of mainframe()]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I am getting error in PyQt5 code. Can any one help me.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView as QWebView

class Browser(QWebView):

    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        print( unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()
    view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
    app.exec_()
```

Output: [Error]

```
  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) 
  <ipython-input-50-e1b5f3fc9054> in _result_available(self, ok)

   13

   14     def _result_available(self, ok):

  ---> 15              frame = self.page().mainFrame()    ------------- [ERROR]

   16         print( unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8'))

   17 

  AttributeError: 'QWebEnginePage' object has no attribute 'mainFrame'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using a Qt Webkit guide that is deprecate from Qt 5.6, it is currently used Qt WebEngine that has changed many classes and methods since it is based on chromium, in this [`link`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html) you can find a guide how to port Qt Webkit to Qt WebEngine . In your case there is no `mainFrame()`, and the way to get HTML is asynchronous:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView as QWebView

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
        if ok:
            frame = self.page()
            frame.toHtml(self.callback)

    def callback(self, html):
        print(unicode(html).encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()
    view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well thanks for the solution. And I saw link but it is C++ API. Can you tell me how i am gonna use it in python or any link for Python.

Comment: @David If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. On the other hand unfortunately there is no documentation adapted for python, but when I pointed out in my answer my intention was for you to read and understand the equivalencies between Qt Webkit and Qt Webengine, the names of the classes and methods are the same in C++ and python so in general you should not have problems to try a translation, on the other hand there are many guides on the internet and related questions in SO.